# Helpshift failing to install from Cocoapods

Tags: ios, ios7, cocoapods, helpshift

Whenever I try to install Helpshift from CocoaPods with `pod install` or `pod update` it fails because the Cloudfront host can't be reached. Is it down? All the other packages in my Podfile seem to install fine.

I have `pod 'Helpshift', '~>4.8.0'` specified in my Podfile. Could this be a problem as I notice there is no 4.8.0 version listed on [the CocoaPods page](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Helpshift/4.9.1/) for Helpshift? I don't think this matters as `pod install` also fails if I specify that I want version 4.9.1.

Here's the error message I get after trying to run `pod install`:

```
Installing Helpshift (4.8.0)

[!] Error installing Helpshift
[!] /usr/bin/curl -L -o /Users/mxd/Code/WordPress-iOS/Pods/Helpshift/file.zip "https://d3e51fp79zp4el.cloudfront.net/library/ios/v4.8/helpshift-sdk-ios-v4.8.0.zip" --create-dirs

 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: d3e51fp79zp4el.cloudfront.net
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Cocoapods down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984087/is-cocoapods-down)

Comment: As noted in the linked question CocoaPods relies on only GitHub. The situation here is the site where this library author hosts their code is down. CocoaPods does not host code.

Comment: Hi,Rhi here from Helpshift mobile SDK team. We have replied to your query on support@helpshift.com. Please let us know if you have any other queries/concerns/suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens it's best to check out https://cocoapods.statuspage.io

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=cloudfront&src=typd) there's a Cloudfront outage currently.